# Postman save response to variable from a schedule request

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

Is it possible to save a response to a variable from a schedule request thats run every hour?

I am getting every hour an bearertoken and I want to save it in my variable so I can automatically send a post call.

I created a schedule and used this script in my Tests:

```
const response = pm.response.json();
console.log(responseBody);
pm.globals.set("BearerTokenMaster", response.access_token);
```

It does not save in my `.globals.BearerTokenMaster`.

My response call would be:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "erpservice"
}
```

Comment: Could you please post that initial response?

Comment: Just added my post.